# Spilt JSON objects to JSON array objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling with a problem. I want to Spilt JSON objects to another javascript arrays objects using javascript. The JSON should be split the last element of the array. it means `{ href: '/Local1', label: 'Local1', group: 'Local', active: ' active' }` and `{ href: '/Local2', label: 'Local2', group: 'Local', active: ' active' }` should contain in `Local` array. `{ href: '/Foreign1', label: 'Foreign1', group: 'Foreign', active: '' }` and `{ href: '/Foreign1', label: 'Foreign1', group: 'Foreign', active: '' }` should be in `Forign` array.

I have mentioned the tried code below. But my code doesn't give me the expected output. What should I do to get the expected output?

```
exports.getMenu = function (selected, username) {
  const menu = [
    [
      ['/Local1', 'Local1', 'Local'],
      ['/Local2', 'Local2', 'Local'],
      ['/Foriegn1', 'Foriegn1', 'Foriegn'],
      ['/Foriegn2', 'Foriegn2', 'Foriegn'],
    ],
  ];

  const xxx = setMenuGroup(selected, menu);
  console.log(xxx);
  return xxx;

}
```

Current Output:

```
[
  [
    { href: '/Local1', label: 'Local1', group: 'Local', active: ' active' },
    { href: '/Local2', label: 'Local2', group: 'Local', active: '' },
    { href: '/Forign1', label: 'Forign1', group: 'Forign', active: '' },
    { href: '/Forign2', label: 'Forign2', group: 'Forign', active: '' }
  ]
]
```

Expected output:

```
{
  Local: [
    { href: '/Local1', label: 'Local1', group: 'Local', active: ' active' },
    { href: '/Local2', label: 'Local2', group: 'Local', active: '' },
  ],
  Forign: [
    { href: '/Forign1', label: 'Forign1', group: 'Forign', active: '' },
    { href: '/Forign2', label: 'Forign2', group: 'Forign', active: '' }
  ],
}
```

Comment: JSON is a string format for JavaScript Objects and is never an "object" and always a string.

Answer (score 0):

didnt test it with your code but you could do it with a second reduce.

```
function setMenuGroup(selected, input) {
  var result = input.reduce( (acc,[href,label,group]) => {
    if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(group))
       acc[group] = [];
    acc[group].push({
      href,
      label,
      active:(selected == href) ? ' active' : ''
    });

     return result.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.group] = r[a.group] || [];
        r[a.group].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

 },{});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```js
input = [{
      href: '/Local1',
      label: 'Local1',
      group: 'Local',
      active: ' active'
    },
    {
      href: '/Local2',
      label: 'Local2',
      group: 'Local',
      active: ''
    },
    {
      href: '/Foreign1',
      label: 'Foreign1',
      group: 'Foreign',
      active: ''
    },
    {
      href: '/Foreign2',
      label: 'Foreign2',
      group: 'Foreign',
      active: ''
    },
];

var result = input.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if(value.group in acc){
    acc[value.group].push(value)
  } else {
    acc[value.group] = [value];
    }
    return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: For this, I am getting `[{Local:[[Object], [Object]], Foreign:[[Object], [Object]]}]` as the result. How can I fix this.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `Array#map` to convert each element of your array of arrays.
2. Use object destructuring when reducing instead of array destructuring.

```js
const getMenu = function (selected, username) {
  const menu = [
      [
        { href: '/Local1', label: 'Local1', group: 'Local', active: ' active' },
        { href: '/Local2', label: 'Local2', group: 'Local', active: '' },
        { href: '/Foreign1', label: 'Foreign1', group: 'Foreign', active: '' },
        { href: '/Foreign2', label: 'Foreign2', group: 'Foreign', active: '' },
      ]
  ]

  const xxx = menu.map(m => setMenuGroup(selected, m));
    return xxx;
}

function setMenuGroup(selected, input) {
  var result = input.reduce( (acc,{href,label,group}) => {
    if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(group))
       acc[group] = [];
    acc[group].push({
      href,
      label,
      active:(selected == href) ? ' active' : ''
    });
    return acc;
 },{});
 return result
};
console.log(getMenu('/Local1'));
```

Comment: For this, I am getting `[{Local:[[Object], [Object]], Foreign:[[Object], [Object]]}]` as the result. How can I fix this.

Comment: I added the my whole code to the quection. Previous I tried to do the minimal code.